# sql chat group same chat

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a chatbox that work similar to facebook inbox.

```
select * from chat where id in(select max(id) from chat where `to`='$user' or `from`='$user' group by `from`)order by id desc"
```

the problem is:

john send message to marie
marie send to john

it will show 2 results. I want to group this same conversation between john and marie in only one select (like facebook do). how can I group by from em to in the same time?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `sent` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `recd` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
);
```

Comment: by having a 'conversations' table as well, and tagging each message with the conversation id.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is the query you are looking for

select group_concat(message) from(
select '$user' btw,messagefrom chat 
where from in('$user1','$user2') or to in('$user1','$user2') 
order by sent) a
group by btw;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36177/3

Answer (score 0):

[This Article](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html) may improve your idea to build a standard chat engine like facebook. At first you have to confirm that you have well designed schema 
[image]